# Select a-element without img inside

Tags: html, css

On an html5 webpage I have a hover-effect. Like this:

```
a:hover {
   background: #EFEFEF;
}
```

I also have a list of images with links:

```
<a href="x">
    <img src="images/y.png" />
</a>
```

When hovering over those links, a #EFEFEF-colored line appears under the image. How do I remove that?

It's not the text-decoration: underline, also fiddling with padding didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely seeing the background of the anchor beneath the image. Set the image's display to block:

```
a img {
  display: block;
}
```

Before and After Demo: http://jsbin.com/enikoz/edit#preview

Keep in mind though that converting an inline image into a block element can affect our layout.

Answer (score 1):

As an enhancement to Jonathan's answer, if you don't want the layout of the element to change, I'd suggest turning the `a` into an `inline-block` as well as making the `img` a `block`.

```
a {display:inline-block}
a img {display:block}
```

That way, the `a` will stay inline, and the text will keep its integrity. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akk9y/1/).

Comment: I think this can be a bit problematic with IE as inline-block is not supported in most versions of it

Comment: True, but in that case, it will degrade gracefully to Jonathan's solution!

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the background color in the whitespace underneath the image; If you remove the whitespace after the image, it should go away:

```
<a href="x">
    <img src="images/y.png" /></a>
```

Comment: @MrLister - Yes, I tested it (http://jsbin.com/iwecil).  However, after a little experimentation it appears this solution only works with either no doctype or an HTML 4.01 transitional doctype; For Strict and HTML 5 doctypes it did not work.

Comment: Yes, but only on IE. Other browsers don't mind the whitespace in quirks mode. That's one quirk which is different in IE than in other browsers, and one more reason never to use quirks mode.

Comment: Thx, but I prefer valid html 5 above quirks mode ;-)

Comment: @MrLister - not just IE, I'm on a Mac, it is happening in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Lennart - That makes sense if you have the choice, I'll leave my answer though as a solution for people with an existing site that they aren't able to spend the time/effort on a full site update.

Answer (score 0):

If your image links point to a common directory or website, you can actually select them by using the attribute selector with a regular expression trick.

```
a[href*="foo"]:hover {
   background:transparent;
}
```

So basically, this will select all the a elements with "foo" in their href attribute. the asterisk before the equal sign acts as a wildcard. Otherwise, it would only select the elements with exactly the "foo" href.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the line you’re seeing is the descender space under the image (which sits on the text baseline) being filled in with the background color.  Try `text-align: bottom` applied to the image itself and see if the line goes away or shifts to the top of the image.  If it doesn’t, try `text-bottom`.

If either of those works, then vertical alignment is the problem, and you can fix it by adding a page-colored background to the image and giving it some bottom padding (say, `0.15em`) while also aligning it to the bottom of the line of text (using `bottom` or `text-bottom` as before).